# WrappInner nests the items being appended while clone return as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to clone an existing object and wrapping it to an `<li>` and then grabbing value property of that checkbox and converting it into a string.

Unfortunately I'm not able to figure out, first, when I try cloning it, it returns as an object; Second I'm not able to wrap properly with an `<li>` tag, all the items that I try to append are being nested to another level.

You can see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2FLkS/1/

and here's the code I'm working:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var list1 = $('#list1 .wrap-item');
    list1.click(function(){
        var cloneItem = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').clone();
            cloneItem = cloneItem + cloneItem.prop('value');
        $("#selected-items").append(cloneItem).wrapInner('<li></li>');
    })
});
```

Comment: `cloneItem = cloneItem + cloneItem.prop('value');` - what?

Comment: You're trying to concantenate an object with a string, and it's not really clear why ?

Comment: You mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/2FLkS/7/ ?

Comment: On this part, cloneItem = cloneItem + cloneItem.prop('value')

I'm trying to get a checkbox an html text next to it. I'm expecting the output will be something like, <input type="checkbox">Value Here

Comment: @Alek, yes, thanks it! but I wanted to include the checkbox in it. It will be a mirror list. Thank You!

Comment: @j08691, you got it! I was trying the same approach earlier, but i looks I missed something. Thank You!

I really appreciate everyones input. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="list1">
    <div class="wrap-item">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="water" value="Water Element">Water</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-item">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="water" value="Fire Element">Fire</label>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-item">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="water" value="Earth Element">Earth</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="list2">
    <ul id="selected-items"></ul>
</div>
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#list1 .wrap-item input').click(function () {
        var copy = $(this).parent().clone(),
            input = $(copy).find('input'),
            text = input[0].nextSibling.nodeValue,
            newText = input.val();
        input[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = newText;
        $('#selected-items').append($(copy).wrap('<li></li>').parent());
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z7xmq/)**